# Java Big number negative?

Tags: java

I tried to get bignumber from a string, but the value in binary is wrong.

```
        priKeyData = HexByteKit.Hex2Byte("b8dfc598d14c0bb032c1f4eb1fcdb033289002f38cc16b2120dfa697f8982bef");
        BigInteger priKeyBN2 = new BigInteger(priKeyData);
        String s3 = priKeyBN2.toString(2);
```

it gives:
-100011100100000001110100110011100101110101100111111010001001111110011010011111000001011000101001110000000110010010011111100110011010111011011111111110100001100011100110011111010010100110111101101111100100000010110010110100000000111011001111101010000010001

But the right one should be:

1011100011011111110001011001100011010001010011000000101110110000001100101100000111110100111010110001111111001101101100000011001100101000100100000000001011110011100011001100000101101011001000010010000011011111101001101001011111111000100110000010101111101111

http://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php

The right one is 256 bit, so it overflows in Java bignumber class?
Then how can I use this 256 bit number for some steps in Java encryption algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: It's interpreting your number as the [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation.  Try adding "00" at the beginning of your hex string to try to force it to be positive.

Comment: Just use the appropriate constructor, allowing to pass the signum (1): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-

Comment: both solution works! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `HexByteKit` is, but constructing `BigInteger` from the hex string gives the right result:

```
BigInteger priKeyBN2 = new BigInteger("b8dfc598d14c0bb032c1f4eb1fcdb033289002f38cc16b2120dfa697f8982bef", 16);
String s3 = priKeyBN2.toString(2);
```

Comment: HexByteKit is this one, just convert hex string to Byte array, https://github.com/johnklee/flib/blob/master/src/flib/util/HexByteKit.java

Comment: your solution works! but i wonder why I converted string to byte array, then passed byte array to BigInteger gave wrong result? (the HexByteKit result seems right..)